# Wordpress PHP echo result with query

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement

I have a list of results on a page (each result is the title of a custom post type). Each custom post has meta data attached (stored in wp_postmeta in the db), one of the bits of meta data is the variable `wedding_hidden_is_completed`

For each of my custom posts where this variable is set to 0, I want to echo an error message.

For example, say I have posts with ID's 1,2,3,4 and only posts 2 and 3 have the variable `wedding_hidden_is_completed` set to 1, then I need to echo 2 separate error messages: Error with Post 1 AND Error with post 4 (these should be wrapped in separate divs).

Here is what I have so far:

```
global $wpdb;
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'bookings',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'wedding_user',
        'value' => $current_user->display_name,
        'compare' => '=',
    )
)
);
// Errors query
$errors_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $errors_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $errors_query->have_posts() ) {
    $errors_query->the_post();

// Fill out form \
$is_form_complete = get_post_meta( $errors_query->post->ID, 'wedding_hidden_is_completed', true );

if($is_form_complete !=1) {
$error_message = '<p>Error with post'.$errors_query->post->ID.'</p>';
}

?>
<div class="errors"><?php echo $error_message; ?></div>
<?php
}
}
```

This currently echos out 4 divs (one for each post type), the first 3 say error with post 1, and the last one says error with post 4. How can I make it so that I only echo a div per error?

UPDATE: code showing all error if statements

```
if($is_form_complete !=1) {
  $error_message = '<p>Booking form ID DISTR'.$errors_query->post->ID.' needs to be completed.</p>';
  echo '<div class="errors"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>'.$error_message.'</div>';
}

// Deposit due
if($is_deposit_paid !=1) {
  $error_message = '<p>Booking form ID DISTR'.$errors_query->post->ID.' deposit now due.</p>';
  echo '<div class="errors"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>'.$error_message.'</div>';
}

// Full Payment due
if($is_full_amt_paid !=1) {
  $error_message = '<p>Booking form ID DISTR'.$errors_query->post->ID.' remaining balance now due.</p>';
  echo '<div class="errors"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>'.$error_message.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

Replace

```
if($is_form_complete !=1) {
$error_message = '<p>Error with post'.$errors_query->post->ID.'</p>';
}

?>
<div class="errors"><?php echo $error_message; ?></div>
<?php
```

With

```
if($is_form_complete !=1) {
  $error_message = '<p>Error with post'.$errors_query->post->ID.'</p>';
  echo '<div class="errors">'.$error_message.'</div>';
}
```

That way you only output the error div when there is an error. This will stop it outputting the same error 3 times as per your example.

**UPDATE:**

For your multiple errors:

Before your loop

```
// Define the variable first and give it a default value
$error_message = null;
```

Then in your loop (using .= lets us add to the variable)

```
// Form not complete
if($is_form_complete !=1) {
  $error_message .= '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><p>Booking form ID DISTR'.$errors_query->post->ID.' needs to be completed.</p>';
}

// Deposit due
if($is_deposit_paid !=1) {
  $error_message .= '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><p>Booking form ID DISTR'.$errors_query->post->ID.' deposit now due.</p>';
}

// Full Payment due
if($is_full_amt_paid !=1) {
  $error_message .= '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><p>Booking form ID DISTR'.$errors_query->post->ID.' remaining balance now due.</p>';
}
```

And finally after closing your loop

```
// Check if there are any errors to display
if($error_message != null) {
  echo '<div class="errors">'.$error_message.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Great stuff - the problem you had was that once you set $error_message it would stay set. So by keeping it all in the conditional (the if) then it only gets displayed when it should :)

Comment: Thanks Simon, I guess in the long run I would rather have all my messages stored as an array (as there will be more if statements) for example if($is_deposit_paid !=1) { - Ideally I'd like to just have one line of code that echo's out all the errors - do you think that is possible?

Comment: Yeah that should be possible - do you want each booking to have an error message or one big error message relating to all the bookings?

Comment: Yep the latter, so at the top of the page - above all the bookings is a list of all the errors relating to the bookings - does that make sense? Let me add all my error if statements to my question